# How to import a JS file in kotlin/JS

Tags: kotlin, three.js, kotlin-js, kotlin-js-interop

I am trying to use THREE.js with kotlin/JS. It works great so far, however, I struggle on how to import the gLTFLoader. The documentation says I should do:

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
```

In kotlin

```
@file:JsModule("three")
@file:JsNonModule
```

at the beginning of a file works.

This

```
@file:JsModule("three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader")
@file:JsNonModule
package mypackage

import org.w3c.xhr.XMLHttpRequest

external class GLTFLoader() {
    fun load(url: String, onLoad: (GLTF) -> Unit, onProgress: (XMLHttpRequest) -> Unit = definedExternally, onError: (dynamic) -> Unit = definedExternally)
}

external class GLTF {
    val scene: Group
}
```

does not work. And

```
@file:JsModule("@three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader")
```

does not work either. In both cases, I get

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '@three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader' in
>   '/my_project_dir/build/js/packages/z-index/kotlin'

The required file is in /my_project_dir/build/js/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js
The main file for Three.js, which apparently can be found, is in /my_project_dir/build/js/node_modules/three/src/Three.js.

How do I do the required import?

Answer (score 1):

You should use require for statements like those
in three.kt, define your definitions

```kotlin
@file:JsModule("three")
@file:JsNonModule
package mypackage

import org.w3c.xhr.XMLHttpRequest

external interface ThreeGLTFLoader() {
    fun load(url: String, onLoad: (GLTF) -> Unit, onProgress: (XMLHttpRequest) -> Unit = definedExternally, onError: (dynamic) -> Unit = definedExternally)
}

external interface GLTF {
    val scene: Group
}
```

then in three.dsl.kt define

```kotlin
val GLTFLoader : ThreeGLTFLoader = require("three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader")
```

now you can use GTFLLoader